# Reading Values from Windows Resource (.res) Files

Tags: windows, winapi, resources

all.  I would like to know if there is a good way to read out values in a compiled resource (*.res) file.  I am familiar with reading resources from an executable, and I'm wondering if there is a similar way to read out resources from a resource file.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm programming in Delphi, though I can usually get examples in other languages.  I assume this sort of functionality would be through the Windows API.

Comment: The Windows API doesn't know anything about .res files.  Can't you just link it?  Visual Studio allows opening them.

Comment: Not really.  I know how to manipulate and link .res files, and that's really not the issue.  I want to be able to modify the resource file right before compile (to include the compile time in the version information).  I could just edit the resource manually every time, but I'd rather automate the process.

Comment: All the system's I've used that add build-time information to the resources either write the build-time info to a small .RC source file that's consumed by the resource compiler, or update the finished .DLL or .EXE with a resource editing program.  I haven't seen one that modifies the .RES file directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows functionality for dealing with res files deals with them almost exclusively as embedded resources. Typically an application will ship with localized resources contained in resource only dlls. LoadLibraryEx takes flags like `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` that are used to prevent the Dlls DllMain being called.

The most help you're going to get from Microsoft wrt loading res files directly is [this MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648007(VS.85).aspx)

---

If manipulation of resources is what you want [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030(VS.85).aspx) UpdateResource, EndUpdateResource is an API you can use to inject (or modify) a version resource in an existing dll.